# Create a column which elements are dictionaries which values are based in another columns of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a column (ColumnE in the table below) in which each element is a dictionary that contains the information of the previous 4 columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'TestA_complete': ["No", "No","Yes"],'TestA_incomplete': ["No", "Yes","No"],  'TestB_complete': ["Yes", "Yes","No"], 'TestB_incomplete': ["No", "No","No"], 
                        'ColumnE': [{"TestA_com":"No","TestA_inc":"No","TestB_com":"Yes","TestB_inc":"No"}, {"TestA_com":"No","TestA_inc":"Yes","TestB_com":"Yes","TestB_inc":"No"},
                                                                                                            {"TestA_com":"Yes","TestA_inc":"No","TestB_com":"No","TestB_inc":"No"}]})
```

```
|    | TestA_complete   | TestA_incomplete   | TestB_complete   | TestB_incomplete   | ColumnE                                                                        |
|---:|:-----------------|:-------------------|:-----------------|:-------------------|:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0 | No               | No                 | Yes              | No                 | {'TestA_com': 'No', 'TestA_inc': 'No', 'TestB_com': 'Yes', 'TestB_inc': 'No'}  |
|  1 | No               | Yes                | Yes              | No                 | {'TestA_com': 'No', 'TestA_inc': 'Yes', 'TestB_com': 'Yes', 'TestB_inc': 'No'} |
|  2 | Yes              | No                 | No               | No                 | {'TestA_com': 'Yes', 'TestA_inc': 'No', 'TestB_com': 'No', 'TestB_inc': 'No'}  |
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df['ColumnE'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(), axis=1)
```

Or

```
df['E'] = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Output (this output includes both ways):

```
  TestA_complete TestA_incomplete TestB_complete TestB_incomplete                                                                                                 ColumnE                                                                                                       E
0             No               No            Yes               No   {'TestA_complete': 'No', 'TestA_incomplete': 'No', 'TestB_complete': 'Yes', 'TestB_incomplete': 'No'}   {'TestA_complete': 'No', 'TestA_incomplete': 'No', 'TestB_complete': 'Yes', 'TestB_incomplete': 'No'}
1             No              Yes            Yes               No  {'TestA_complete': 'No', 'TestA_incomplete': 'Yes', 'TestB_complete': 'Yes', 'TestB_incomplete': 'No'}  {'TestA_complete': 'No', 'TestA_incomplete': 'Yes', 'TestB_complete': 'Yes', 'TestB_incomplete': 'No'}
2            Yes               No             No               No   {'TestA_complete': 'Yes', 'TestA_incomplete': 'No', 'TestB_complete': 'No', 'TestB_incomplete': 'No'}   {'TestA_complete': 'Yes', 'TestA_incomplete': 'No', 'TestB_complete': 'No', 'TestB_incomplete': 'No'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, that worked! What if you want to update the values inside the dictionaries of the columnE? For example if there is another column (TestA_complete2: "Yes","No","Yes") that you need to use to update the values of the key "TestA_complete" along the entire column?

Comment: Yeah, you can update the entire column, or you can do it by row also using the apply I method.

Comment: Nice! Could you write an example line for me please? I don't know how to use apply to update values inside dictionaries of a column. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df['ColumnE'].tolist(),index=df.index)
Out[41]: 
  TestA_com TestA_inc TestB_com TestB_inc
0        No        No       Yes        No
1        No       Yes       Yes        No
2       Yes        No        No        No
```

If only need the ColumnE

```
df['new'] = df.to_dict('index').values()
```

Comment: I think you have mistaken me, I want to create the "columnE", not the other columns. Thanks anyway

Comment: @BENY I think the OP means that the input dataframe is only the first four columns and they want to create ColumnE from the first four columns.

Comment: @ScottBoston that's correct, sorry for the confusion